# Boolean Logic - Conversion from AND to OR and OR to AND

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, binary, binary-operations

is there a simple boolean equation that :

| Given | Equals |
| --- | --- |
| A+B | AB |
| AB | A+B |
| !A+!B | !A!B |
| !A!B | !A+!B |

I figured that it would require to flip the sign, but then it lead me to this

| Given | Flip | Equals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | A | !AB |
| A+B | B | A+!B |
| A!B | AB | !AB |
| A+!B | BA | !A+B |

I do not understand how to necesarily word it, so I figured that the table would work better. Would the first one be considerd "flipping the function"?

When it comes to gates, `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, `NOR`, `NAND`,`XOR`,`XNOR` are able to be used, so pretty much anything is on the table.

Closest i have been would be to simply run the equation through `NOT`, and it flips froms DeMorgan's Theorem.

Comment: This is *really* unclear.  $AB$ is not logically equivalent to $A + B$ ... so what is this 'flipping' supposed to accomplish? Indeed, what is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Bram28 AB isn't supposed to be equivalent to A+B. I was wondering if there was a chain of operations that could result in AB from A+B. I didn't know how to refer to it, but the "flipping" was turning the `AND` operator to an `OR` operator for the first example, and inverting a predefined Boolean variable for the other. I attempted to do this with the `NOT` operator, but it also changed the sign, which wasn't desired

Comment: Is there a chain of operations that changes $A + B$ into $A\cdot B$? Yes, change $+$ into $\cdot$ .... which is of course far too obvious.... Sorry, I must still not be understanding what you're trying to do

Comment: @Bram28. Given the an electrical signal that indicates for the boolean algebra `A+B` and a handful of physical `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, and `XOR` gates, is there any way that i can turn that electrical signal into the boolean algebra `A*B`. I understand that I can just `AND` A and B, but these were simply used as examples.

Comment: So all you have is a single $A+B$ signal?  I see no way to    change tgat into a $AB$ signal… unless you have access to the individual $A$ and $B$ signals … but if you have those, we’re back to just AND-ing those.

Answer (score 1):

The up arrow is the Sheffer stroke symbol ($\uparrow$) represents the NAND. The down arrow is the Peirce's arrow symbol ($\downarrow$) and represents the NOR. Both of these are universal gates. This means that using one of them you can create any gate or operation you want. They can do any form of computation. But for the sake of this example, we just show AND versus OR.

$$(A \uparrow B) \uparrow (A \uparrow B) = A \land B$$

$$(A \downarrow B) \downarrow (A \downarrow B) = A \lor B$$

If you are able to swap the universal gates on the fly you have changed the two operations. Otherwise you would have to make some more complicated circuit that can swap signals based on an IF-statement and reroute the signals to one of these gates based on your input.

There is not just one way to to this; If you read the OR- and AND-constructions you can also swap the signals $A$ with $B$:

$$(A \downarrow A) \downarrow (B \downarrow B) = A \land B$$

into:

$$(A \downarrow B) \downarrow (A \downarrow B) = A \lor B$$
using only NOR-gates.

So what this last example shows is that if we swap the second and third signal we swap the entire operation from AND to OR. Swap it back to get from OR to AND etc.

Here's the entire list of swapping AND to OR and OR to AND using NOR or NAND:

Using NOR gates:

```
A OR B  = (A NOR B) NOR (A NOR B)
A AND B = (A NOR A) NOR (B NOR B)
```

Using NAND gates:

```
A AND B = (A NAND B) NAND (A NAND B)
A OR B  = (A NAND A) NAND (B NAND B)
```

**Conclusion**

There are two ways to turn AND into OR or OR into AND. Either swap the logical gate (logic operator) or reroute the signal going into two of the lines inside the circuit.